# is it possible Apply PCA on any Text Classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, naivebayes

I'm trying a classification with python. I'm using Naive Bayes MultinomialNB classifier for the web pages (Retrieving data form web to text , later I classify this text: web classification).

Now, I'm trying to apply PCA on this data, but python is giving some errors.

My code for classification with Naive Bayes :

```
from sklearn import PCA
from sklearn import RandomizedPCA
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
classifer = MultinomialNB(alpha=.01)

x_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(temizdata)
classifer.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This naive bayes classification gives that output :

```
>>> x_train
<43x4429 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6302 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> print(x_train)
(0, 2966)   1
(0, 1974)   1
(0, 3296)   1
..
..
(42, 1629)  1
(42, 2833)  1
(42, 876)   1
```

Than I try to apply PCA on my data (`temizdata`) :

```
>>> v_temizdata = vectorizer.fit_transform(temizdata)
>>> pca_t = PCA.fit_transform(v_temizdata)
>>> pca_t = PCA().fit_transform(v_temizdata)
```

but this raise following erros:

> raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense ' TypeError: A
>   sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray()
>   to convert to a dense numpy array.

I convert matrix to densematrix or numpy array. Then I tried to classfy new densematrix , but I have error.

My main aim is that test PCA effect on Classification on text.

Convert to dense array :

```
v_temizdatatodense = v_temizdata.todense()
pca_t = PCA().fit_transform(v_temizdatatodense)
```

Finally try classfy :

```
classifer.fit(pca_t,y_train)
```

error for final classfy :

> raise ValueError("Input X must be non-negative") ValueError: Input X
>   must be non-negative

On one side my data (`temizdata`) is put in Naive Bayes only, on the other side `temizdata` firstly put in PCA (for reduce inputs) than classify.
__

Comment: I don't see why this should not work. How do you convert to a dense array and what error do you get then?

Comment: Are you using an old version of scikit-learn? I don't think `from sklearn import PCA` is possible in recent versions...

Comment: @kazemakase Im sorry I write wrong. I can convert to dense or numpy but NaiveBayes not working with new dense matrix. I added

Answer (score 25):

Rather than converting a `sparse` matrix to `dense` (which is discouraged), I would use scikits-learn's [`TruncatedSVD`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html), which is a PCA-like dimmensionality reduction algorithm (using by default Randomized SVD) which works on sparse data:

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5, random_state=42)
data = svd.fit_transform(data)
```

And, citing from the `TruncatedSVD` documentation:

> In particular, truncated SVD works on term count/tf-idf matrices as returned by the vectorizers in sklearn.feature_extraction.text. In that context, it is known as latent semantic analysis (LSA).

which is exactly your use case.

Comment: This appears more useful than my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks comment . But after TruncatedSVD ,  naivebayes classification gave same  error :

 raise ValueError("Input X must be non-negative")
ValueError: Input X must be non-negative

Comment: @zer03 as the error tells you, you cannot pass a negative features to the MultinomialNB, and dimensionality reduction algorithms tend to do so (put the data in the [-1, 1] range). So, either you choose another training algorithm (different from NB), or you don't apply PCA, but you cannot use both together. From the [documentation of MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html): `The multinomial distribution normally requires integer feature counts. However, in practice, fractional counts such as tf-idf may also work.`.

Comment: @kazemakase you were also right in the part that only positive numbers are permitted with NB, so if the OP still wants to use `MultinomialNB`, my answer is no longer valid. But if he still wants to do dimensionality reduction, `TruncatedSVD` is the way to go.

Comment: @imaluenge. thanks very much bro. Actually,  I has researching tf-idf . If I cant do with another classification (forexample, SVM etc.) I 'll start to study tf-idf. Actually My main goal is distinguish classification / PCA (or feature reduced ) applied classification

Answer (score 5):

The `NaiveBayes` classifier needs discrete-valued features, but the PCA breaks this property of the features. You will have to use a different classifier if you want to use PCA.

There may be other dimensionality reduction methods that work with NB, but I don't know about those. Maybe simple [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) could work.

side note: You could try to discretize the features after applying the PCA, but I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks very much all answers @kazemakase. You helped me too. 

for side note , this method maybe effect bad to result. But, even so I'll try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by applying dimensionality reduction, you will generate negative features. However, Multinominal NB does not take negative features. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169238/dealing-with-negative-values-in-sklearn-multinomialnb) questions.

Try another classifier such as RandomForest or try using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()`  to scale your training features to `[0,1]`